# Meaning in Original vs. Summarized Texts

Tags: semantics, summarization

I've been wondering for a while now if it is possible to compare two texts - an original text and a summarized/simplified version of it in terms of meaning?

Specifically, whether or not meaning is lost due to lack of vocabulary in the case of the summarized/simplified version?

If so, how does one go about performing such an analysis?

Also, which branch/sub-branch of linguistics deals with such issues?

Comment: "Meaning" is not a term used when being specific. How can you tell whether meaning is lost? Measurement? Testing? Word count? How can you tell which part is the meaning in the first place? Realistically, no branch of linguistics deals with this; there are too many variables and vaguenesses.

Comment: @jlawler, that's exactly what I'm asking. For instance, The Declaration of Independence of the US has simplified versions, which are written with a limited vocabulary compred to the original text. I would like to know whether or not it is possible to examine if the simplified version is able to adequetly convey the message of the original text using a limited set of words.

Answer (score 1):

For example, we could compare the OP and the following text:

> How can one compare two texts to see if they mean the same thing?
> Which branch of linguistics does this?

The answer to the second question is "None: that is in the domain of philosophy". The reason is that linguistics presupposes certain results from philosophy, basically the question "What do you mean by 'mean'?". I would say that the two texts mean the same thing, because they perform the same communicative function, requesting information about linguistic analysis. Somebody else may have a different view of what "meaning is" so they may conclude that the texts do not mean the same thing. There is no linguistic resolution of this matter.

If you posit that meaning is "the entirety of information content", you would get a different answer. In removing the text "I've been wondering for a while", I removed some information about you personal state that I considered to not be essential to the communicative function of your text. Now the question is if there are any two texts that are textually-distinct but informationally identical. Compare the three texts "The cat is on the sofa", "The cat is on the couch", "The cat is on the davenport". Although the actions and entities conveyed here is the same, the choice of lexical items conveys information about you (information includes misinformation, fyi). I learn something about your age and Great Lakes origin if you say davenport, and something (murky) about your world view if you say "sofa" (I would learn even more if you say something indicating that a sofa is different from a couch).

Until we definitively sort out what the "meaning" of a text is, linguists can't compare the meanings of two texts.